# React Router Switch inside of Context Provider causes constant flickering (rerendering)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context

I need to access the same state in all routes of my react router. But when I put the `SchedulerContext.Provider` around the React Router `Switch` component I get a constant rerendering (flickering) of one route. I'm wondering if the problem lies in using the context around the `Switch` or somewhere else.

I've noticed it only happens with the component of the first route (Dash).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    scheduler: {
      ...defaultSchedulerContext,
      fetchScheduledPosts: () => {
        axios
          .post(`${defaultSchedulerContext.API_ENDPOINT}/list`)
          .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
              this.setState(state => ({
                scheduler: {
                  ...state.scheduler,
                  postsList: res.data
                }
              }))
            } else {
              this.setState(state => ({
                scheduler: {
                  ...state.scheduler,
                  errorMessage: res.status
                }
              }))
            }
          })
      }
    },
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <SchedulerContext.Provider value={this.state.scheduler}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={withAuth(Dash)} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          </Switch>
        </SchedulerContext.Provider>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by using reach/router instead of react-router.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **higher order component** you can add the context providers to the Route component rather than wrapping the switch itself in the context providers.

```
const AddContextProviders: = (Component) => {
  const hoc = (props: any) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(1);

    return (
      <SchedulerContext.Provider value={state}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </SchedulerContext.Provider>
    );
  };

  return hoc;
};

const RouteWithContext = AddContextProviders(Route)
const App = () => {
  return (<Switch>
        <RouteWithContext exact path="/" component={withAuth(Dash)} />
        <RouteWithContext path="/login" component={Login} />
        <RouteWithContext path="/register" component={Register} />
      </Switch>)
}
```